# Implement a mechanism for chaining messages in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, block

I'm writing an app which requires running a method after another method completes. (Common scenario, right?)

I'm trying to implement chained methods. The best I've come up with is to call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`. I'm simply not sure if that is the best way to do this. I've looked into how the Cocos2d game engine implements its `CCSequence` class, but I'm not sure I understand it.

I suspect blocks would do well here, except I'm not sure how to use them as callback objects or whatever.

How would I implement a mechanism for running methods, one after the other? (I'm open to using timers or blocks, but I don't know how I'd use blocks in this case.)

**Edit:**

To clarify, I'm trying to implement a system like cocos2d's `CCSequence` class, which takes a few methods and "dispatches" them in sequence. Things like animations, which take much more than a single clock cycle to run.

I'm not looking to block the main thread, nor do I want to hard code methods to each other. Cocos2d has a sequencing system where I can pass in methods to a queue and run them sequentially.

**Edit 2:**

Also, I'd like to be able to cancel my scheduled queues, and so I'm not sure GCD is a good match for this. Can GCD serial queues be canceled?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague.  Normally you would just call the second method at the end of the body of the first method, or call the second method after calling the first method, from the code that calls the first method.  Why don't either of those work for you?

Comment: @robmayoff See my edits - I'm looking for a specific method of flexible call chaining.

Comment: I think Rob has a point. This sounds a lot like over-engineering. You already have CCSequence and CCCallFunc/CCCallBlock at your disposal, and they can be cancelled. Why not use those? Yes, you will be blocking the main thread but is this really an issue? If it is, then there's a good chance your game won't perform well on devices with a single-core CPU.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'm trying to get away with not using cocos2d at all for this project here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found what I'm looking for. Completion blocks. Simply put, I'd write a method like this:

```
- (void) performSomeActionWithCompletion:(void (^)()) completion{

     [self someAction];

     if(completion()){
       completion(); 
     }

}
```

Now I can call my method like so:

```
[self performSomeActionWithCompletion:^{
  NSLog(@"All done! (Well, not the async stuff, but at any rate...)");
}];
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)` on the `if(completion())` line...

Comment: You need to define a block type first.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the technique of **[Thread Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1)**

Then here comes the interesting task called **GCD-Grand Central Dispatch**

> Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) is a technology developed by Apple Inc.
>   to optimize application support for systems with multi-core processors
>   and other symmetric multiprocessing systems.It is an implementation of
>   task parallelism based on the thread pool pattern.
>
> GCD works by allowing specific tasks in a program that can be run in
>   parallel to be queued up for execution and, depending on availability
>   of processing resources, scheduling them to execute on any of the
>   available processor cores
>
> **Dispatch Queues** are objects that maintain a queue of tasks, either anonymous code blocks or functions, and execute these tasks in their
>   turn. The library automatically creates several queues with different
>   priority levels that execute several tasks concurrently, selecting the
>   optimal number of tasks to run based on the operating environment. A
>   client to the library may also create any number of serial queues,
>   which execute tasks in the order they are submitted, one at a time.
>   Because a serial queue can only run one task at a time, each task
>   submitted to the queue is critical with regard to the other tasks on
>   the queue, and thus a serial queue can be used instead of a lock on a
>   contended resource.
>
> Dispatch queues execute their tasks concurrently with respect to other
>   dispatch queues. The serialization of tasks is limited to the tasks in
>   a single dispatch queue.
>
> **In your case you can use Serial Dispatch Queues**
>
> Serial queues are useful when you want your tasks to execute in a
>   specific order. A serial queue executes only one task at a time and
>   always pulls tasks from the head of the queue. You might use a serial
>   queue instead of a lock to protect a shared resource or mutable data
>   structure. Unlike a lock, a serial queue ensures that tasks are
>   executed in a predictable order. And as long as you submit your tasks
>   to a serial queue asynchronously, the queue can never deadlock.
>
> Unlike concurrent queues, which are created for you, you must
>   explicitly create and manage any serial queues you want to use. You
>   can create any number of serial queues for your application but should
>   avoid creating large numbers of serial queues solely as a means to
>   execute as many tasks simultaneously as you can. If you want to
>   execute large numbers of tasks concurrently, submit them to one of the
>   global concurrent queues. When creating serial queues, try to identify
>   a purpose for each queue, such as protecting a resource or
>   synchronizing some key behavior of your application.
>
> ```
> dispatch_queue_t queue;
>
> queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
> ```
>
> this code shows the steps required to create a custom serial queue.
>   The dispatch_queue_create function takes two parameters: the queue
>   name and a set of queue attributes. The debugger and performance tools
>   display the queue name to help you track how your tasks are being
>   executed. The queue attributes are reserved for future use and should
>   be NULL.
>
> Grand Central Dispatch provides functions to let you access several
>   common dispatch queues from your application:
>
> Use the **dispatch_get_current_queue** function for debugging purposes
>   or to test the identity of the current queue. Calling this function
>   from inside a block object returns the queue to which the block was
>   submitted (and on which it is now presumably running). Calling this
>   function from outside of a block returns the default concurrent queue
>   for your application.
>
> Use the **dispatch_get_main_queue** function to get the serial
>   dispatch queue associated with your application’s main thread. This
>   queue is created automatically for Cocoa applications and for
>   applications that either call the dispatch_main function or configure
>   a run loop (using either the CFRunLoopRef type or an NSRunLoop object)
>   on the main thread.
>
> Use the **dispatch_get_global_queue** function to get any of the
>   shared concurrent queues.
>
> Note: You do not need to retain or release any of the global dispatch
>   queues, including the concurrent dispatch queues or the main dispatch
>   queue. Any attempts to retain or release the queues are ignored.

**Source: [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html)**

Answer (score 6):

What about using a serial GCD queue?

> private dispatch queues
>
> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (which can vary from task to task) that is managed by the dispatch queue. Serial queues are often used to synchronize access to a specific resource.
> You can create as many serial queues as you need, and each queue operates concurrently with respect to all other queues. In other words, if you create four serial queues, each queue executes only one task at a time but up to four tasks could still execute concurrently, one from each queue. For information on how to create serial queues, see “Creating Serial Dispatch Queues.”

([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html))

This would be useful if you want that all of your messages be handled in a background thread.

Answer (score 2):

There are two performSelector method that can wait for completion, no need to guess a timing.

```
[self performSelector:<#(SEL)#> onThread:<#(NSThread *)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to check out `NSOperationQueue`, `NSOperation`, and either `NSBlockOperation` or `NSInvocationOperation`.  Unlike a GCD queue, an `NSOperationQueue` supports cancelling jobs.

You can create your own queue and set its maximum concurrent operation count to 1 to force it to execute operations serially.  Or you can set dependencies between operations to force those operations to run serially.

Start with the chapter on Operation Queues in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1).